# X,Y,Z are independent, and $Z\overset{d}{=}X+Y$, then $Z-X\overset{d}{=}Y$?

Tags: probability

> Q: The three random variables X,Y and Z are independent, and suppose that $Z\overset{d}{=}X+Y$, then $Z-X\overset{d}{=}Y$ ?

I am not sure whether this is true. Since the variables are independent, we have
$$Z\overset{d}{=}X+Y \Longrightarrow  F_Z=F_X * F_Y.$$
And $Z-X\overset{d}{=}Y$ holds if and only if
$$ F_Z *F_{-X}=F_Y.$$
But I don't know how to calculate the convolution $F_X *F_{-X}$, and maybe there are other ways to prove or disprove this ?

Comment: No - consider variances, or finite interval support

Answer (score 2):

The conclusion fails whenever $X$ is non-degenerate!

Let $f,g,h$ be the characteristic functions of $X,Y$ and $Z$ respectively. Then $h=fg$.  If the conclusion holds then $ h\overline f=g$. Multiply both sides by $f$ to get $h|f|^{2}=fg=h$. Hence, $|f|^{2}=1$ in some interval around $0$. This implies that $X$ is a constant r.v. Putting it differently, we can move $X$ to the left side in $Z\overset{d}{=}X+Y$ if and only if $X$ is a constant.

Also, when variances exist you can get a contradiction immediately (if $Var (X) \neq 0$) by taking variance on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Here one counter example. Suppose $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent normal distributed random variables, each one  with mean $0$,  and variances $1$, $1$ and $2$ respectively.
THen $Z\stackrel{d}{=} X+Y$, however $Y\stackrel{d}{=}Z-Y$ is false

Answer (score 0):

Another counterexample: If $X, Y$ are both coin flips (i.e. both $0$ or $1$ with equal probability), then $Z$ would be $0, 1, 2$ with various probabilities; hence, $Z- X$ could be $2$ or $-1$ with positive probability.